# Get path of a file using "Send to" shortcut to a Win32 app (Flutter Desktop)

Tags: winapi, desktop-application, flutter-desktop

It's easy to add the app in the "Send To" folder. But once you select a file --> send to --> your app, the app just opens.

[image]

In the above picture, once I click on "Your App", the app opens, but how do I get the absolute path of the file that is selected? I can't find anything related to this.

Comment: Have you seen the command line arguments?

Answer (score 0):

The file name is probably the first argument, which is used, when your application is called.

Your main function has to look like this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

Then argc is the count of arguments and argv an array of null terminated strings.

The first argument would be accessed like this:

```
argv[1];
```

But don't forget to check argc first:

```
char* cFile=0;
if(argc==1) {
   cFile=argv[1];
}
if(cFile) {
 //do action with file here
}
```

Comment: But where do I find the first argument? is there something I need to add in main.cpp to get the file name/ file path

Comment: The last command line position `argc - 1` where the parameter sent by "Send To" folder resides are something contained full path. You can use `PathCchRemoveFileSpec` to get file path or use `_splitpath_s` to get the file name and file path.